# Java 8: How to convert List<Map<String, String>> to List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java

A list object containing a `Map<String, String>` objects need to pass as argument having parameter of type `List<Map<String, Object>>`.
 I need to cast it like this -

```
List<Map<String, Object>> objectList = (List<Map<String, Object>>) (Object) strList;
```

Is there any better approach here? Is it good idea to cast like given above? Will Java 8 Stream be a better option for conversion?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you show more of the context? Why is it passed as an `Object`? Why are you casting it to an `Object` in the first place? etc.

Comment: Can you change the API to accept a `List<Map<String, ?>>`?

Comment: I am getting the above list object strList from the web layer, my service layer api accept only of type objectList . so that is why need to cast and create objectList  before passing it to service api.

Comment: @DavidConrad You might need `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you can change the target parameter to type `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`

If you want to construct a new object matching the target type,

```
List<Map<String, Object>> objectList = strList.stream()
        .map(map -> map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (Object)e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has an unsafe type cast warning, but I believe in the case suppressing warnings is justified as the data is known to be compatible.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> objectList = 
        list.stream()
            .map(m -> (Map<String, ?>) m)
            .map(m -> (Map<String, Object>) m) //warning
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Although the stream has little more than just type casts, it still creates  a new collection, so it would be better to just change your downstream API to accept both type arguments:

```
private static <T extends Object> void 
        doSomething(List<Map<String, T>> objectList) {}
```

And you can call it with either type:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = null;
List<Map<String, Object>> objectList = null;

doSomething(objectList);
doSomething(list);
```

Comment: @Prem Joshi comments are appreciated. Does this answer your question?